# Peewee silently inserts empty values for not-null columns without defaults into MySQL on strict mode

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

There's no error raised when calling `save()`, `create()`, or `insert().execute()` on a model instantiated with one or more fields omitted, even on fields configured as `null=False` and `default=None` ([the default setting for all fields](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#field-initialization-arguments)) despite MySQL being configured to use strict mode globally:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode="TRADITIONAL";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

```
from rich import inspect

from peewee import Model, MySQLDatabase
from peewee import CharField, FixedCharField, BooleanField, DateTimeField

debug_db = MySQLDatabase(
    database = 'debug_db',
    user = 'DEBUG',
    host = 'localhost',
    password = 'secret'
)

class Person(Model):    
    first_name = CharField(32)
    last_name = CharField(32, null=False)
    email = FixedCharField(255)
    signup_time = DateTimeField()
    approved = BooleanField()
    
    class Meta:
        database = debug_db

debug_db.connect()
debug_db.create_tables([Person])

john_doe = Person(
    first_name = "John"
)

inspect(john_doe)

# │     approved = None                             │
# │ dirty_fields = [<CharField: Person.first_name>] │
# │        email = None                             │
# │   first_name = 'John'                           │
# │           id = None                             │
# │    last_name = None                             │
# │  signup_time = None                             │

john_doe.save()

# mysql> select * from person;
# +----+------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+----------+
# | id | first_name | last_name | email | signup_time         | approved |
# +----+------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+----------+
# |  1 | John       |           |       | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |        0 |
# +----+------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+----------+
# 1 row in set (0.00 sec)

# Debug logger:
# ('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_type != %s ORDER BY table_name', ('VIEW',))
# ('INSERT INTO `person` (`first_name`) VALUES (%s)', ['John'])
```

On strict mode, the equivalent `INSERT` statement issued directly to MySQL throws an error:

```
# mysql> INSERT INTO person (first_name) VALUES ("John");
# ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'last_name' doesn't have a default value
```

As shown in the example, inspecting the instance reveals the omitted attributes are set to `None` internally. Interestingly, doing so manually triggers an error in Peewee and includes the `None`-valued field in the generated SQL:

```python
john_doe = Person(
    first_name = "John",
    last_name = None
)

# peewee.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'last_name' cannot be null")

# Debug logger:
# ('INSERT INTO `person` (`first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES (%s, %s)', ['John', None])
```

In Peewee's documentation, the chapter on querying includes [an example](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#creating-a-new-record) of gradually assigning values to an object created with some fields initially omitted, so allowing omission at instantiation must be intentional, but I would expect an error at some point before the row is inserted, either arising from the resulting SQL statement or when calling `save()`.

By comparison, using SQLite instead of MySQL triggers an error in Peewee:

```
peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: person.last_name
```

I've also tested using `playhouse.mysql_ext.MySQLConnectorDatabase`, which produces the same result as the default MySQL driver.

I'm on Peewee 3.17, MySQL 8.0.31, and Python 3.10.5.

Comment: You need to set your Peewee connection to use strict mode if you want strict mode.

Comment: Peewee overrides that when establishing the connection? Even without strict mode, how come the behavior is different for SQLite?

Comment: Because that's how mysql was designed! In not strict mode will use data type's default value in the absence of a default one.

Comment: @Shadow In the MySQL version I'm using, the default `sql_mode` includes one of the three strict mode options, specifically `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, which raises an error for the `INSERT` above. It doesn't just insert the implicit default.

Comment: So you have strict mode enabled for transactional tables by default. Great. This setting, however, can be overridden in the session (connection).

Comment: @Shadow Not just can, it's done by default, overriding not just MySQL's default, but also the drivers' default behavior, which is why it's unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Peewee sets the `sql_mode` connection parameter by default, overriding any global SQL mode (including [MySQL's default SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-sql-modes.html)), so as pointed out by coleifer, it's necessary to manually set `sql_mode` when establishing a connection to stop incomplete inserts with strict mode:

```
debug_db = MySQLDatabase(
    # ...
    sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL' # One of 3 strict modes; not the MySQL default.
)
```

Specifically, Peewee overrides the `sql_mode` connection parameter (otherwise `None` in both PyMySQL and MySQL Connector/Python) in `MySQLDatabase` and its `MySQLConnectorDatabase` subclass in order to set the SQL mode `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`:

```
#line 4147 of peewee.py (within the MySQLDatabase class definition)
sql_mode = "PIPES_AS_CONCAT"
```

To keep `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` without overriding the global SQL mode, it's possible to just append it instead, using the `init_command` connection parameter while resetting Peewee's `sql_mode` override:

```
debug_db = MySQLDatabase(
    # ...
    sql_mode = None,
    init_command = "SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode,',PIPES_AS_CONCAT'));"
)
```